# I need help outputting squares of numbers separated by commas

Tags: vb.net

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text ^ 2
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = Nothing
    TextBox2.Text = Nothing
End Sub
```

End Class
The code above outputs squares of any single values input in textbox1 but i need some help in inputting a couple of values separated by commas and then output the squares of those individual values eg 3,4 the output 9,16

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do it all for you, because this looks like homework, but here are some pointers:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text ^ 2
```

1) Turn on Option Strict, by placing `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file or by putting it in the project properties Compile tab. This will help you be more rigorous with your coding. Here you're taking a string (`TextBox1.Text`) and having VB auto convert it to a number (which might fail), squaring it, and then auto converting it back to a string to store in `TextBox2.Text`. This is bad news all round; always be crystal clear in your own mind and explicit in your coding about the difference between various data types.A string containing numbers is not the same thing as a number!

2) Rename your textboxes after you drop them on a form. Nothing is more frustrating than to read a block of code where the variable names are irrelevant garbage. You will find this when you come back to some complex code in 6 months and think "what the..."; renaming a textbox so it is called `resultTextBox` or `inputTextBox` takes seconds and makes your code instantly more comprehensible to both you and anyone you call in to help out with it

> separated by commas

The following line of code will split a string into an array of strings, on comma:

```
Dim csv = "3,6"
Dim arr = csv.Split(","c) 

Console.WriteLine(arr(0)) 'prints 3
Console.WriteLine(arr(1)) 'prints 6
```

The following line of code will convert a string to an integer:

```
Dim s = "3"
Dim i = Convert.ToInt32(s)
```

Maths operations can now be performed on it

```
i = i * i 'square it
```

The following line of code will turn an integer into a string:

```
Dim i as Integer = 3
Dim s as String = i.ToString() 's is now "3"
```

The following line of code will loop through an array, appending the values in the array to a string variable, and adding commas. Finally it trims off the excess trailing comma

```
Dim s as New String
For Each x as String in arr
  s = s & x & ","
Next x
s = s.TrimEnd(","c)
```

Here is another way too, using the String.Join helper method:

```
Dim s as String = String.Join(","c, arr)
```